# Mixing stacked and unstacked bars

Tags: charts, birt, bar-chart

i just made my first steps with birt charting api. i created some stacked and not-stacked (grouped) bar charts, but i need also a mix of them: some of the bar series should be stacked and some of the should be grouped. how to achieve this?

(setting some but not all series to bs1.setStacked(true); yields an exception ...  contains a mix of stacked and unstacked series.)

but it should work?!:

http://wiki.eclipse.org/BIRT/FAQ/Charts2.2#Can_I_combine_stacked.2C_logarithmic_and.2For_percent_properties_on_a_single_scale.3F

Answer (score 1):

got an answer from Jason Weathersby in [Eclipse' forum](http://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/372732/). the crux is to define 2 SeriesDefinition one for the stacked BarSeries (setStacked(true);) and one for the not-stacked BarSeries:

```
 ...
BarSeries bs1 = (BarSeries) BarSeriesImpl.create();
bs1.setDataSet(orthoValues1);
bs1.setStacked(true);

BarSeries bs2 = (BarSeries) BarSeriesImpl.create();
bs2.setDataSet(orthoValues2);
bs2.setStacked(true);

BarSeries bs3 = (BarSeries) BarSeriesImpl.create();
bs3.setDataSet(orthoValues3);
bs3.setStacked(false);

SeriesDefinition sdY = SeriesDefinitionImpl.create();
sdY.getSeriesPalette().shift(0);
yAxisPrimary.getSeriesDefinitions().add(sdY);

SeriesDefinition sdY2 = SeriesDefinitionImpl.create();
sdY2.getSeriesPalette().shift(0);
yAxisPrimary.getSeriesDefinitions().add(sdY2);  

sdY.getSeries().add(bs1);
sdY.getSeries().add(bs2);
sdY2.getSeries().add(bs3);
...
```